# render react component in gatsby-remark markdown

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am using gatsby-remark for my blog.

I would like to render rect components by specifiying the components in the markdown.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `rehype-react`

Check a full tutorial on how to implement it here: https://using-remark.gatsbyjs.org/custom-components/